# pgfplots piece-wise defined path not aligning

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I was trying to imitate a question ([Drawing closed 3d path with pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460449/drawing-closed-3d-path-with-pgfplots)) and do a piecewise-defined curve in pgfplots, but my plots are not aligning on the z-axis, despite the math (assuming I didn't flub my calculations) saying they should. Changing the multiple of pi in the second addplot3 doesn't usually change it unless I do a large multiple like 25 or 200. Making them into separate \begin{axis}...\end{axis} environments doesn't make it work either.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
    \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,view={135}{45},xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,zlabel=$z$,clip=false,xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,ztick=\empty]
            \addplot3[double,domain=0:180,samples=90,samples y=1] 
            ({1-cos(2*x)},{-sin(2*x)},{0.125*sin(4*x)-0.5*x});
            \addplot3[double,domain=180:360,samples=90,samples y=1] 
            ({cos(2*x)-1},{-sin(2*x)},{0.5*x-0.125*sin(4*x)-pi});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \]
\end{document}
```

Is there an easy way of making the plots "align" properly (the top loop should be shifted downwards with respect to the z axis so that it forms a closed loop) that I am overlooking? The z-axis also looks to be uneven unlike the x and y so I don't know if that is a symptom of whatever is going on. Thanks for any insight!
[image]

---

EDIT: with a very good catch from KersouMan (thank you!!), it appears I mixed the pi in with degrees, so editing for that (using 180 instead of pi), I get a loop as desired, but it is significantly more wacky than it should be. Pictured below:

[image]

The graph *should* look more like a very plain figure 8 (composed of two kissing circles) if you project to the x,y-plane.

How it should look (or sort of, at least) is like this:
[image]

---

EDIT 2: Here is some better code to replicate the third image above:

```
        \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,view={135}{45},xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,zlabel=$z$,clip=false,xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,ztick=\empty,zmax=120]
            \addplot3[double,domain=0:180,samples=90,samples y=1] 
            ({1-cos(2*x)},{-sin(2*x)},{0.125*sin(4*x)-0.5*x});

            \addplot3[double,domain=180:360,samples=90,samples y=1] 
            ({cos(2*x)-1},{-sin(2*x)},{0.5*x-0.125*sin(4*x)-180});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \]
```

[image]

I feel like there is a little distortion here and there (maybe it is the viewing angle?), but otherwise, decent enough. I am glad it is at least now a closed loop!

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail what `align` mean? I.e. in which way does the output not coincide with your expectation. (BTW, it is appreciated if you add a complete document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.)

Comment: If I understand well what you want to plot, I think the problem is in your formula for the second curve. By using `({cos(2*x)-1},{sin(2*x)},{0.5*x-0.125*sin(4*x)-0.5*180})`, I obtain a continuous line (and do not use pi in your formulas if the domain is set in degrees). It is even simpler if you use `({cos(2*x)-1},{sin(2*x)},{0.5*x-0.125*sin(4*x)})` with `domain=0:180` as the second plot.

Comment: @marmot I have edited accordingly

Comment: @KersouMan thank you!! That fixes one problem, but another problem now presents itself: the z-axis is all messed up, and the loop still doesn't quite look like it should! I will try to edit a picture to show how I wish it would look. See the edit for how it looks now.

Comment: @anakhro Could you try using `({cos(2*x)-1},{sin(2*x)},{0.5*x-0.125*sin(4*x)})` with `domain=0:180` for the second plot? It seems to yield what you want.

Comment: You can add some appropriate `zmax` to the axis options.

Comment: @KersouMan That gave me a single, continous path, but it was not closed. See the third picture I have just added.

Comment: @marmot that seems to have fixed it partially, let me fiddle with it and see if I can fine tune it!

Comment: The distortion may not be from the view angle but from the fact that you patch these graphs together.

Comment: @marmot the function as a whole should be smooth, or at least I tried to construct it so that is the case. Maybe you are right, though. Unless you mean that this will happen with most piece-wise defined functions in pgf, then I am not sure. In any case, thank you for your help with the zmax option, that seems to help. On another note, does anyone know why plotting two paths in this way result in them being sometimes displaced from each other (or messing up the axes)?

Comment: Worth noting that I also noted I plotted them in the wrong order, so it appears as an illusion, but I fixed that on my side. :P

Answer (score 1):

This is a proposal to draw the curve in one plot. Depending on what you want to achieve, you may be better off with `trig format=rad`, which allows you to specify the angles in radians. I do not have the full picture of what you are after.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}
 \[
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,view={135}{45},xlabel=$x$,
        ylabel=$y$,zlabel=$z$,clip=false,xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,ztick=\empty,zmax=120]
            \addplot3[double,domain=0:360,samples=181,samples y=1] 
            ({sign(180-x)*(1-cos(2*x))},{-sin(2*x)},
            {ifthenelse(x<180,0.125*sin(4*x)-0.5*x,0.5*x-0.125*sin(4*x)-180)});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice! I do like the overlap of the original, however, just to give it that 3D element.